# Swift http post request sends empty body to server

Tags: node.js, swift, post

I am trying to perform a simple http post request from swift to a nodejs server. When i run the following code, the body seems to arrive empty. I have tried several variants on it, with no success.

CLIENT: SWIFT 5.

```
func api_post(){

        struct User: Codable {
            let username: String
            let password: String
        }

        let user = User(username: "ausername",password: "apassword")
        guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) else {
            return
        }



        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/post")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpBody = uploadData




          let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print ("ERROR: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                    print ("SERVER ERROR")
                    return
                }
            if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
                mimeType == "application/json",
                let data = data,
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print ("RETURNED DATA: \(dataString)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

}
```

Result:

```
POST!
{}
```

CURL into the same url does work as expected:

```
curl -d "username=ausername&password=apassword" -X POST http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX/post
```

Result:

```
FROM SERVER: POST RESPONSE [OK]
```

SERVER: NodeJs and ExpressJs.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = XXXX

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))





app.post('/post', function (req, res) {
    console.log("POST!");
    var data = JSON.stringify(req.body,null,2);
    console.log(data)
    res.send ("FROM SERVER: POST RESPONSE [OK]");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I have pretty much copied and pasted from Swift's documentation and still it's not working as expected. I would suspect of my server code, but curl does work. So I am unsure what's the problem.

Thanks you!

Comment: Do: `let bodyStr = String(data: request.httpBody, encoding: .utf8)`, and print it. What's printed? I guessed it's printed: `{"username":"ausername", "password"="apassword"}`, it's not in URLEncoded version.

Comment: Printed:
{\"username\":\"ausername\",\"password\":\"apassword\"}

Comment: I don't speak JS, but "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))" expect `username=ausername&password=apassword` not JSON as you are sending. That's why you are finding the value empty.

Comment: Larme, just found out the answer and posted two seconds ago. Ha. Yes. My problem was related to json on the server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out. The problem was on the Server side. Adding this line made it work. (bp is NPM bodyParser)

```
app.use(bp.json()); // support json encoded bodies
```

Result now is as expected:

```
POST!
{ username: 'ausername', password: 'a password' }
```